# Error boost filtering_ostream when returned from a function

Tags: c++, boost, gzip, iostream

just a quick question regarding boost::iostream::filtering_ostream().

I have a function which (internally) creates a shared_ptr to a boost::iostream::filtering_ostream, and returns a shared pointer to a std::ostream.

Whenever I don't use a compressor in the function, everything seems to work fine, but as soon as I add a compressor, the output file becomes corrupt.  If I write the text within the 'getOutputStreamComp' function, everything works then also.

The example below just writes some numbers to a file, just as a POC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> getOutputStream(const std::string& fileName)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream> out(boost::shared_ptr<boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream>(new boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream()));
    out->push(boost::iostreams::file_sink(fileName),std::ofstream::binary);

    return out;
}

boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> getOutputStreamComp(const std::string& fileName)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream> out(boost::shared_ptr<boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream>(new boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream()));
    out->push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    out->push(boost::iostreams::file_sink(fileName),std::ofstream::binary);

    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> outFile     = getOutputStream("test.txt");
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> outFileComp = getOutputStreamComp("testcomp.txt.gz");

    // This file is fine.
    for (size_t i(0); i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        *outFile << "i: " << i << std::endl;
    }

    // This file is corrupt.
    for (size_t i(0); i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        *outFileComp << "i: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Any ideas that you might have would be gratefully received!

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the issue, with help from [Cubbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273767/cubbi) - the following line(which appears twice):

```
out->push(boost::iostreams::file_sink(fileName),std::ofstream::binary);
```

should have been:

```
out->push(boost::iostreams::file_sink(fileName,std::ofstream::binary));
```

The code was still compiling, so I was probably setting a flag somewhere in the filtering_ostream, which may have led to issues further down the line.

This fix allows the file to be created as expected.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the typos (`*outFile` and `*outFileComp`), I cannot reproduce this: compiling with g++ 4.8.1/boost-1.53, it runs and produces two good files: `test.txt` with 10,000 lines (file size 78,890) and `testcomp.txt.gz` (file size 22,064) which unpacks with gunzip into the exact copy of `test.txt`.

Perhaps in your real program, you tried examining the file before the program ended (or at least before the last reference to the shared_ptr was gone)? A common gotcha of compressed filtered streams is that flushing `outFileComp` as you do with `std::endl` does not force the complete writeout of the compressed file so far.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, the getOutputStream and getOutputStreamComp functions are exactly copied from my code, but the rest was just for an example.  Will think more & type less next time.
You might be right with your guess - I'm going to run through it a few more times and see if I can figure out what's up.  I'm using VS2012 Express, if that helps.
Thanks for taking a look, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, so I think I figured this out - there was a typo when pushing the file_sink to the filtering_ostream, but one that allowed the code to still compile.  I had written the following:
`out->push(boost::iostreams::file_sink(fileName),std::ofstream::binary);`,
when it should have been:

`out->push(boost::iostreams::file_sink(fileName,std::ofstream::binary));`

This seems to fix the problem on my windows machine, and everything works great.
Thanks again for your input Cubbi, I'm grateful you took the time!

Comment: @DaveM That was indeed easy to miss! I tested on a linux box, where text and binary don't differ, so of course your program worked for me as-is. You may wish to post your result as an answer and accept that instead, to make this more useful for future readers.